# Return value of a UDF as a column in Select clause - Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions, snowflake-schema

We have a scenario in which I have a User defined function in Snowflake that returns a value that I would like to use as a column name in a select clause to fetch from another table. Is it feasible or is there a workaround to meet this requirement?

Eg: Below is the Metadata table from which i fetch the value using function. The values in this table are the valid columns from another table

[image]

Function:

[image]

My requirement is i want to use this function to fetch the result of the column from another table, based on the parameter i pass the column will change, if i pass 1 then i need the result of P_YEARS_CLEAN_IND , if 2 then i need the result P_YEARS_CLEAN_IND_2. However when i use the function  in the select clause as shown below, it just return the string 'P_YEARS_CLEAN_IND_2' instead of the actual result, as function output is treated as string. Is there a way to achieve my need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_CAPPING_LOGIC(RB_COL_NM VARCHAR, CAP_PROJ_TERM NUMBER
)
RETURNS TABLE ()
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
COL_NAME  VARCHAR  DEFAULT (SELECT CASE WHEN :CAP_PROJ_TERM = 0 THEN SF_COL_NM
                                    WHEN :CAP_PROJ_TERM = 1 THEN CAP_TERM_1
                                    WHEN :CAP_PROJ_TERM = 2 THEN CAP_TERM_2
                                    WHEN :CAP_PROJ_TERM = 3 THEN CAP_TERM_3
                                    END
                             FROM AUTO_CAPPING_DTLS WHERE DATABASE_COL_NAME = :RB_COL_NM);

FINAL_RESULT RESULTSET DEFAULT (SELECT IDENTIFIER(:COL_NAME) FROM POL_TBL);

BEGIN
RETURN TABLE(FINAL_RESULT);
END;
```

call GET_CAPPING_LOGIC('P_YEARS_CLEAN_IND',0);

Comment: Thank you, @Uma. However, the requirement is to call GET_CAPPING_LOGIC multiple times in the select clause, and based on the parameters, I need to get different columns. If it is a procedure, I will be unable to invoke it in the select clause, and my requirement will be unsatisfied.

Answer (score 0):

This is not feasible to achieve my requirement just with the UDF, I have used python along with SQL to achieve my needs. Thanks !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).